# How to list all files under /etc and write it to a file in /home?

Tags: linux, permissions, ls, command, aws

```
ls -a > /home/etc.txt
-bash: /home/etc.txt: Permission denied
```

I'm in `/etc` trying to list all the things under it and write it all into a text file in `/home`... but I'm getting permission denied.

I am in my own server in AWS logged in as `ec2-user`, but currently `sudo whoami` shows `root`. I should be able to do this right?

Comment: Do you actually intend to write to a file under `/home` or to a file in your home directory (`$HOME/etc.txt` or `~/etc.txt` or `/home/yourusername/etc.txt`)?  Users don't usually have write access to the `/home` directory itself.

Comment: @Kusalananda im in aws ec2 linux server logged in as ec2-user though

Comment: @Wickerman what user Kusalananda is saying is that your user, unless they have root(sudo) permissions cannot write to `/home` only their own like `/home/user` Please edit your post to specify your exact goal. Thank you.

Comment: @kemotep What if I use sudo -s? My ecs server only accepts single user mode escalation

Comment: @kemotep $ sudo whoami
root

Comment: @Wickerman `/home` is a directory for user "home" directories. You should never really write to it but to an actual user's home like `/home/user`. You can short hand this as `~` so in your example you do this: `~/etc.txt` which would be a file located at `/home/user/etc.txt`. Think of home as the same as `C:/Users` in Windows. Just because you could potentially save files there does mean that that choice makes much sense. P.S. `sudo whoami` will always show root because that is what sudo does. Give the command root permissions.

Comment: If you would use `ls -a /etc > /home/etc.txt` you'll need write permissions for your user in `/home`. If you would use `sudo ls -a /etc > /home/etc.txt` you'll still need write permission for your user in `/home` because the output redirection is not used by the `sudo` command but at the active shell itself.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/82256/7479590 for a similar question.

Comment: The "*list all files under /etc*" in the Title is irrelevant and misleading.  The real question seems to be "*How to create a file in /home?*".

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to write this to your home directory rather than `/home`. You home directory will normally be `/home/username`, or you can use `~` which represents your home directory.

You should you `find` rather than `ls` to find all files under `/etc`.

```
find /etc -type f > ~/etc.txt
```

Using `find` like this could also be error prone though, if files have a newline in the name for example.

Comment: The command, `ls`, has the option, `-R`, which is used to recursively list.

Comment: I know it's pretty despicable to be asking homework questions but...

"3. List the detailed content of path /etc and output to file “etc.txt” under path /home"

Would that mean home directory or literally path /home?

Is it even possible to write to /home?

Comment: It's not at all despicable to ask homework questions here. We'd prefer that we knew it was homework, but most importantly make sure you're on the right side of the fine line between asking for help and plagiarism.

Comment: @Christopher Sure, it won't output a list of just the files though, it outputs the directories the files are in and blank lines. That could all be filtered out of course but `find` is more appropriate for this.

Comment: if you say find is better than ls you should also say why. With -ls option find would output "details" as  demanded. Still we don't know about .hidden files. But why not simply translate, word for word: LIST [ls] THE DETAILED [-l][-a] CONTENT OF PATH [-R] /ETC [/etc] AND OUTPUT [>] TO FILE ETC.TXT [etc.txt]

Answer (score 1):

```
 "...under path /home"
```

Does it really say so? That would explain all this misunderstanding. "Under path $HOME" would make more sense...

`/home/$USER` could be another notation for "your" home directory. Normally it should just ask you to "create a etc.txt in your home directory"

For a "detailed content" use also `-l` option:

```
ls -alR /etc >~/etc.txt
```

or

```
cd
ls -lR /etc >etc.txt
```

(`cd` alone means `cd ~` means `cd $HOME` means `cd /home/wickerman`)

(The `-a` option is questionable here for /etc)

Answer (score 0):

I'm still very new to this, sorry if I confused everybody.

Anyway, I figured it out.

```
sudo -s #turns me into root

cd /etc
ls -a > /home/etc.txt
```

Comment: You didn't confuse us, I hope that you learned something ;-)

Comment: If you wrote the file into your own home directory you wouldn't need the root privileges.

Comment: @roaima Apparently I needed to write it into root, and I was being tested to see if I could do it.

Comment: Your exercise was testing to see whether you could get root access? The fact that it asked you to create a file where files _very seldom_ are created (if ever) should make you ask yourself what the level of competence of the questioner is. One could have tested that in several _ordinary_ ways.